Gradio error: TypeError: gradio.data_classes.FileData() argument after ** must be a mapping, not list
I was trying to build my first interface in Gradio, when I got this error: "Gradio error: TypeError: gradio.data_classes.FileData() argument after ** must be a mapping, not list" (Full error is below the code block).
import gradio as gr
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd
import random

css = """
.custom-file-input {
    height: 50px;
}
"""

with gr.Blocks(css=css) as ui:
    gr.Markdown(value='#### File for analysis:')
    
    with gr.Row():
        file_input = gr.File(label="Excel or CSV file", elem_classes="custom-file-input", file_count=1)
        analyze_button = gr.Button("Analyze", scale=0)
    
    gr.Markdown(value='### Progress:')
    progress_output = gr.Markdown()
    
    status_text = gr.Textbox(interactive=False, show_label=False, visible=True)
    
    result_file = gr.File(label="Result", interactive=False)
    
    @analyze_button.click(inputs=file_input)
    def process_file(file):
    
        # Simulate file processing and progress updates
        progress = gr.Progress()
        progress(0, desc='0%')
        
        df = pd.read_excel(file.name)
        n_lines = df.shape[0]
        
        for i in range(n_lines):
            # sleep(0.01)  # Simulate some processing time
            df.iloc[i]['Target'] = random.choice(['MOROCCO', 'PRODUCT SKI', 'FINANCE', 'DOMESTIC'])
            progress((i + 1) / n_lines, desc=f'{int((i + 1) / n_lines * 100)}%')

        progress(1, desc='100%')
        
        output_file = "processed_file.xlsx"
        
        df.to_excel(output_file, index=False)
        

ui.launch()

I don't know what to try hoenestly, because it's a new library for me. I tried building a simple gradio interface that reads an excel file and prints out what's inside and it works flawlessly. So, I am guessing it has something to do with handling of output_file probably. Maybe not.
To reproduce: Put any excel file with a few lines of text in the gradio interface and press "Analyze" button to the right of it.
Ful error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abaxt\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\gradio\queueing.py", line 532, in process_events
    response = await route_utils.call_process_api(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\abaxt\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\gradio\route_utils.py", line 276, in call_process_api
    output = await app.get_blocks().process_api(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\abaxt\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\gradio\blocks.py", line 1924, in process_api
    inputs = await self.preprocess_data(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\abaxt\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\gradio\blocks.py", line 1653, in preprocess_data
    inputs_cached = block.data_model(**inputs_cached)  # type: ignore
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: gradio.data_classes.FileData() argument after ** must be a mapping, not list


always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

All problem is file_count=1
Documentation for File shows allowed values:

file_count="single"   (it is default value)
file_count="multiple"
file_count="directory"

So you need
file_input = gr.File(label="Excel or CSV file", elem_classes="custom-file-input", file_count="single")

or you can even skip file_count="single" because it is default value
file_input = gr.File(label="Excel or CSV file", elem_classes="custom-file-input")

That's all.

BTW:
Later you need some small changes.
In function you needs outputs to show progressbar:
@analyze_button.click(inputs=file_input, outputs=progress_output)

If you want to load csv then you have to run read_csv
if file.name.endswith('csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv(file.name)
else:
    df = pd.read_excel(file.name)

